# Unable to retrieve dynamically generated content from localStorage

Tags: javascript, variables, save, local-storage

I have an HTML table with the id "roster1" that allows users to add table rows with a button click, and I am attempting to save the table state via a "Save" button that runs the following piece of code:

```
function saveRoster () {
        localStorage.setItem('rosterPd1','');
        var roster = document.getElementById ('roster1');
        localStorage.setItem('rosterPd1', roster);
        }
```

If I input some static value into 'rosterPd1', then I can use the information written to localStorage with no problem. However, when I attempt to save the table by using the above code, I get [object HTMLTableElement] returned... which is CORRECT, but not particularly useful!

Can someone point me in the right direction on what I would have to do to get localStorage to save the contents of the table itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only save *Strings* to *Storage*, but it seems for what you're trying to do, *innerHTML* will suffice;

```
function saveRoster() {
    var roster = document.getElementById('roster1');
    if (!roster) return; // not found
    localStorage.setItem('rosterPd1', roster.innerHTML); // store innerHTML
}
function loadRoster() {
    var roster = document.getElementById('roster1');
    if (!roster) return; // not found
    roster.innerHTML = localStorage.getItem('rosterPd1'); // get+apply innerHTML
}
```

As for why you're getting `[object HTMLTableElement]`, this is what happens when you call `toString` on a *JavaScript* reference to a `<table>`.

```
document.createElement('table').toString() // "[object HTMLTableElement]"
```

Comment: Thanks Paul. And thanks again for the bonus of answering why I was getting the return I was. Sorry - don't have enough rep yet to upvote, but you nailed it in one!